# What is the right type in ajax function when use .NET MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Recently,When I migrate one of my `.NET Framework` Application to .NET Core 1.1.Howerver,I meet a question, When I use Ajax in Views to invoke Controller method, but i found Controller can't receive the params. I puzzled. Anyone can help me how to figure out that. Detail below:

Here is code in .NET Core:

Views (html):

```
<input id="btnSubmit" type="button" style="font-size: 14px; padding: 2px 4px;" 
       value="OK,Submit!" />
```

Controller (C#):

```
[NeedLogin]
public async Task<string> AddQuestion(QuestionItem qes)
{
    //...
}
```

QuestionItem is Entity object.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: '{"qes":' + JSON.stringify(question) + '}',
        url: '/q/AddQuestion',
        dataType: 'Text',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.indexOf("Add Failed") !== -1) {
                showDialogCustom("Tips", data);
                $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false).val("Ok,Commit!");
            } else {
                if (!$("#txtQuestionMarkdown").length) {
                    tinyMCE.get('txtContent').setContent("");
                }
                $("#txtQuestion,#mySingleField").val("");
                jutil.storage.deleteStorage("q_t");
                jutil.storage.deleteStorage("q_c");
                if (question.SaveOption) {
                    window.top.location.href = "/q/SaveDraftSuccess?qid=" + data;
                } else {
                    window.top.location.href = "/q/success?qid=" + data;
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            showDialogCustom("Wrong!", msg.responseText);
            $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false).val("Ok,Commit!");
        }
    });
```

And I want to know Why my Controller can't receive the `qes` params in .NET Core Application?
And I run it successfully in .NET Framework Application.
What the data or dataType should be ?

Comment: Are you logged in? Does `NeedLogin` pass? Also, you should change dataType to `application/JSON` rather than text (since it *is* JSON). You also may have to specify `[HttpPost]` on the method and `[FromBody]` on the argument (`[FromBody] QuestionItem qes`)

Comment: Yes, I login in, also I debugged, and when i debug into this Controller method. The params qes is null. But I use the `Chrome Developer Tools` find the qes is not null. So I guess it could be the dataType and ContentType. And last night ,I change datatype to `application/json`, add `[HttpPost]` and `[FromBody]`. It doesn't work.

Comment: Nothing (with respect to what your have shown). You code would not work correctly in any version of MVC. What is your `question` object?

Comment: Sorry, I hide some code in-front-of the `$.ajax` code, some properties in `question` object is get from the user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And in last hours, I continue to debug my question,thank you for @Rob. And I found the solutions below:

```
Controller(C#)
 [HttpPost]
 [NeedLogin]
 public async Task<string> AddQuestion([FromBody] QuestionItem qes)
 {
  //...
 }
```

And in Js below:

```
  js
       data: JSON.stringify(question)),
       type: 'post',
       dataType: 'json',
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

And now, the Controller receive the params correctly.

Supply: Recently, when I migrate my project to `.NET Core`, I found many error like what I said in my question.And i found it is not correct answer that I describe before.Because I found my project it's not submit by `Form`. It's use Ajax. And the Answer is `ContentType` in my ajax function

```
  JS
   data: question,*
   type: 'post',
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'*
```

It solved my problem at last!

Comment: `[FromBody]` is the default for a `[HttpPost]` and is not required in this case

Comment: And all you would have needed is `data: question` and omit `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`

Comment: Let me have a try. Thanks .

Comment: I test my project as you said, when i delete the `[FromBody]` and the Controller can't receive the params. So the `[FromBody]` is needed. Then, I add the `[FromBody]` and omit the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` .It run successfully. Thank you anymore.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have seen posts arguing that, but in my experience [FromBody] has *always* been required for POST requests with complex types

Comment: @Rob, Not if the ajax call is sending the default `contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` (and not stringified).